# Jquery functions Delay shortens with each Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure how to ask this question. I made a jQuery function for a banner.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ionanim();
  setInterval(ionanim, 12000);

  function ionanim() {
    $(function () {
      $('.ion1anim').fadeIn(500, function () {
        $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
      });
    });

    $(function () {
      $('.ion2anim').delay(6000).fadeIn(500, function () {
        $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
      });
    });
  };

});
```

Link for the full animation : http://jsfiddle.net/L8XHL/11/

But with each intervatl on the setInverval the animations go close to each other after some time they overlap each other.

Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: No, you didn't do anything wrong, the timing just isn't as accurate as you need it to be to do something like this. You should be using callbacks rather than static delays to ensure that things happen in the order you intend. I also would suggest not using setInterval in this case.

Comment: So what is the best wat to loop the function instead of a setInterval?

This was the best solution based on the searches i did, comes out to be not perfect as you suggest!

Comment: A function that calls itself when all the animations are complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intervals and animations aren't exact enough to handle the timing that you require. I'd suggest using a self-executing function instead so that it will never overlap.

Also, you are over-using the document ready handler. Please stop.

http://jsfiddle.net/L8XHL/13/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ionanim();
    function ionanim() {
        $('.ion1anim').fadeIn(500, function () {
            $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function () {
                $('.ion2anim').fadeIn(500, function () {
                    $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut(500,ionanim);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I would further modify this to work more like a slider so that you can add an infinite number of items without having a huge pyramid of code.

http://jsfiddle.net/L8XHL/17/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ionbanner .bottom div").first().siblings().hide();
    anim();
    function anim() {
        var curr = $(".ionbanner .bottom :visible");
        var next = curr.next();
        if (next.length == 0) {
            next = curr.siblings().first();
        }
        curr.delay(5000).fadeOut(500,function(){
            next.fadeIn(500,anim);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. By over-using the document ready handler you mean in the jsfiddle? like once the jsfiddle domReady and again in the script?

Comment: No, you had `$(function(){})` wrapping each animation. `$(function(){})` is identical to `$(document).ready(function(){})` See the update, i added another way that is cleaner and easier to maintain (you can add more items to cycle through without modifying the code)

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L8XHL/16/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var anim1 = function() {
            $('.ion1anim').fadeIn(1000, anim1Callback);
        },
        anim1Callback = function() {
            $('.ion1anim').fadeOut(1000, anim2);
        },
        anim2 = function() {
            $('.ion2anim').fadeIn(1000, anim2Callback);
        },
        anim2Callback = function() {
            $('.ion2anim').fadeOut(1000, anim1);
        };

    anim1();
});
```

Comment: This works as well, thanks for the contribution. Just found the other answer to be more properly suited for my case!